# Search in Microsoft Office option

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, search

The option in Office's software like Word, Excel, contains lots of information and when we need to go into something we have to remember where to go for.

I wish I would search for a configuration, say, to turn spelling on/off quickly by entering the search box `spelling` and click the configuration from the opened results. The same thing are so convenient in Control Panel for Windows 7.

Is there any work around for that?

Comment: The help documentation onversions of Office after 2003 are all online in many cases.

Comment: @Ramhound And we have to look for it by our own eyes right? We found the right article online then we will have to open the option in the Option menu. You might see how it is convinient in Chrome browser configuration search box

Comment: Every single feature is documented in Help within Word.  Online tutorials are sometimes just easier to folow.

Answer (score 2):

This was first released back when the ribbon was new to Office and people were mighty confused about where their familiar menus and easily accessible commands had disappeared:

> [**Search Commands**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28559) is an Office Labs experiment designed to quickly find the commands you need in Microsoft Office 2007 and 2010 Word, Excel and PowerPoint. Just search with your own words and click on the command you need.

**Note:** Windows XP, Windows Vista & Windows 7 32/64 bit Microsoft Office Word, Excel, and PowerPoint (2010 or 2007) English only. Works with Word, Excel and PowerPoint only.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If you want something that'll work with all the other apps including Outlook, Access, InfoPath, Publisher, MS Project and Visio, there's a commercial alternative available called [**Ribbon Finder for Office**](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-search.php?search_term=ribbon+finder):

[image: 3]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I'm looking for search box in `Option` not for the command

Comment: The add-in often displays commands that are otherwise not available from the ribbon. Try it and see, it might help in your case. I don't know of any other way for you to search through all available options in the Office apps.